# Bootstrap Modal closes on submit

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I've been searching for a while for a solution to this issue, but nothing seems to be working... I have a form within a modal from bootstrap, and I need to perform validation on the form before submitting. On submission it just goes to another page, simple.

But when the validation fails, what I want is for the modal to **not** close, the form will not submit (already in place), and then I have some jquery-ui effects on the form fields. I've tried things like:

```
$('#modalDiv').modal('show');
```

when validation returns false, or adding that to that modal's hide.bs.modal event, but it just wigs out, goes away, and leaves the backdrop in place...?

Could there be some kind of conflict between bootstrap and jquery-ui? I'm surprised there isn't a simple way of disabling modal close on form submit, but I guess I'm not the first one to get into that debate lol. Any suggestions??

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/it2sNCJpqH

Comment: This is great, but I'm not getting what part of it is actually stopping the popup from closing - is it just the validation plugin that it's using?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  if so, maybe provide me an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037565/form-within-bootsrtap-modal-closes-the-model-on-submit

Answer (score 2):

I have been searching for a solution for a long time. I came up with the following "solution" I'd rather call a workaround. I removed the html form element and the used ajax for the validation.

**HTML Code:**

```
    <div class="modal fade"  id="addCategoryModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Category</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="categoryName">Category Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryName" placeholder="Category Name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="submit" id="addCategoryBtn">Submit</button>
                </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <div id="message-warning" style="display: none;"></div>
             <div id="message-success" style="display: none;"></div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**AJAX Code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

/* Add Category*/ 
$('#addCategoryBtn').click(function() {
      var categoryName = $('#categoryName').val();

      if (categoryName == "") {
                $('#message-warning').html("Please add Category");
                $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
      }
      else{

      var data = 'categoryName=' + categoryName;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(msg) {

            // Category was added
            if (msg == 'OK') {
               $('#message-warning').hide();
               $('#categoryName').val("");
               $('#message-success').html("Category Added");
               $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
            }
            // There was an error
            else {
               $('#message-warning').html(msg);
               $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
            }

          }

      });
    }
});//End Add Category


});//End Document Ready Function
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - this was too long ago for me to remember exactly the case and switched jobs so I don't have the code anymore... but hope this will be helpful!